# Interface Builder - Xcode link broken with iPad-converted xib

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, interface-builder

In porting my app to a universal iPhone / iPad app, the xibs I created by using Interface Builder's "Create iPad Version" will not link to the project properly: They don't pick up on classes and images from the project file.

IB tells me that "there is no xcode project associated with this document" with a gray light in the status bar. Yet the xib is in the project, was launched by double-clicking in xcode, and both are open. The old xibs work fine though. I don't understand what could be causing this.

[image]
<sub>(source: [akhun.com](http://akhun.com/seo/skitch/MainView-iPad-20100324-161355.jpg))</sub>

[image]
<sub>(source: [akhun.com](http://akhun.com/seo/skitch/RootViewController.m_-_iLaugh-20100324-161431.jpg))</sub>

[image]
<sub>(source: [akhun.com](http://akhun.com/seo/skitch/Main_View-20100323-235025.jpg))</sub>

So, my question is, how do I restore the link?

Answer (score 1):

See this link - [cocoabuilder-xcode-and-ib-connection](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/xcode/279306-xcode-and-ib-connection.html)

I could solve my problem by

1.quit IB
2.quit xcode / close project file
3.Open Xcode project file by double clicking the file from Finder.
4.Open the nib file from xcode.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an iPad-specific error. I have it on an iPhone app, but I have just moved my project to an SCM repository and all my xib image links are missing. I'm trying desperately to locate any fixed links. Nothing yet.

Will post if I find anything. What I discover may help you.

EDIT: I just reread your original post and mine symptoms are not exactly the same. I'll post what I find anyway.

EDIT: I got mine to work by doing the following:

1. Did a Build-Clean All
2. Did a TOUCH on the troublesome xib file
3. Did another Build-Clean All

All my links were fixed after this. This may not help with your issue, but it worked for me. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: Thnks for the input. Unfortunately, that didn't do the trick for me. No change. :(

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. Copied the project folder to a new location and re-opened new projected, sorted it out.

Answer (score 0):

Making sure the resource path will fix this issue, it seems.